# tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable order mismatch error

Tags: tsqlt

i am try to run one test, I got below error, So can you guys pls help me on this to fix this?

| pub_id | avg_price |
| --- | --- |
| 0736 | 9.784 |
| 0877 | 15.41 |
| 1389 | 18.976 |
| ALL | 14.7662 |

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE DemoUnitTestClass.[testrepq1]
    AS
    BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('actual') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE actual;
    IF OBJECT_ID('expected') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE expected;
    
    CREATE TABLE actual (
    pub_id varchar(10),
    avg_price varchar(10)
    );
    
    INSERT INTO actual (pub_id, avg_price) exec reptq1
    
    CREATE TABLE expected (
    pub_id varchar(10),
    avg_price varchar(10)
    );
    
    INSERT INTO expected (pub_id, avg_price) SELECT '0736','9.784';
    INSERT INTO expected (pub_id, avg_price) SELECT '0877','15.41';
    INSERT INTO expected (pub_id, avg_price) SELECT '1389','18.976';
    INSERT INTO expected (pub_id, avg_price) SELECT 'ALL','14.7662';
    
    EXEC tSQLt.AssertEqualsTable 'expected', 'actual';
    END;
    
    
    (2 rows affected)
    [DemoUnitTestClass].[testrepq1] failed: (Failure) Unexpected/missing resultset rows!
    |_m_|pub_id|avg_price|
    +---+------+---------+
    |  |1389  |18.98    |
    |>  |0736  |9.78     |
    |>  |ALL   |14.77    |
     
    +----------------------+
    |Test Execution Summary|
    +----------------------+
     
    |No|Test Case Name                 |Dur(ms)|Result |
    +--+-------------------------------+-------+-------+
    |1 |[DemoUnitTestClass].[testrepq1]|     14|Failure|
```

in rept1 i used order by id so it always return in order but this is failing the result because of order.

Comment: Your problem is not to do with ordering; `AssertEqualsTable` doesn't consider record order. Some rows are missing/edited from the detailed test failure report; if `expected` contains 4 rows, the failure report should include at least 4 rows, with an `_m_` value for each of them - what you have posted includes 3 rows, one of which has a missing `_m_` value.

Comment: The easiest way to debug this might be to add `select * from expected` and `select * from actual` to the test after the execution of `reptql`; that way you will be able to see clearly what each table contains.

Comment: Thanks @EdHarper you are right, it not about order its about number round. as your suggestion I added select query for both actual and expected i came to know about that difference easily. thanks for your valuable suggestion.